# Problem using a model association in a Rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration, associations

I´m trying to fix some problems adding a column to comments table and performing some updates. But all day having this error:

> rake aborted! An error has occurred,
>   all later migrations canceled:
>
> You have a nil object when you didn't
>   expect it! You might have expected an
>   instance of ActiveRecord::Base. The
>   error occurred while evaluating nil.[]

Migration code:

```
class AddCommenterNameToComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :comments, :commenter_name, :string
    Comment.reset_column_information

    #to update all comments with commenter name
    Comment.all.each do |comment|
      unless comment.is_system_message?
          comment.update_attribute(:commenter_name, comment.user.name )
      end
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :comments, :commenter_name
  end
end
```

Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The association might not be the problem, but to test if it is you could search the User object by passing in the `user_id` column from the Comments table. So, for example:
Edited with OP Proposed fix

```
class AddCommenterNameToComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
  def self.up
    add_column :comments, :commenter_name, :string
    Comment.reset_column_information

    #to update all comments with commenter name
    Comment.all.each do |comment|
      unless comment.is_system_message?
        user = User.find_by_id(comment.user_id)
        if user
          comment.update_attribute(:commenter_name, user.name )
        else
          comment.update_attribute(:commenter_name, "User deleted" )
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :comments, :commenter_name
  end
end
```

Now that said, the problem could be that you have a user_id in the comments table which no longer corresponds to a User object in the Users table. You might want to check for that as well, in case the association turns out not to be the problem.

Comment: Hi Willian, actually, for simplicity, I´ve removed this validation from code. My original has: 

`Comment.all.each do |comment|
      unless comment.is_system_message?
        if comment.user
          comment.update_attribute(:commenter_name, comment.user.name )
        else
          comment.update_attribute(:commenter_name, "User deleted" )
        end
      end
    end`

I´ve also changed with the User.find_by_id, but still raising an error.

Comment: Does it give any line numbers?

Comment: Also, and though it will result in lots of output, try putting a `p comment.inspect` or something in the each loop to see on which comment object it errors out.

Comment: I´ve put the `p comment.inspect` and the problem starts at the first comment that has a user_id. The first 7 comments are system_comments so the problem seems to be at the `if comment.user` line.

Comment: Try changing that to `if !comment.user_id.nil?` instead

Comment: But what I´m trying to test is if there is an user with that id, no if the `user_id` is null on that comment. That´s why, in my first tought, it would be an associantion problem...

Comment: I´ve put this code into a method in a controller and made a route to that. It worked OK. But when I use this conde on the migration, the error happens.

Comment: ah, ok, I see. That makes sense. I updated my answer...try that and see if it works.  Problem is the `.name` on `nil` (the return of User.find_by_id when the user_id on the comment is no longer a User in the system) I think.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem persists. I can't perform the `User.find_by_id`, even if I set a fixed (and existent) id. This is pretty weird because I have made something similar before.

Comment: This have solved the problem: (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#using-models-in-your-migrations). I used `class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  end`and `class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  end` at the beginning of the migration and everything started to work fine. William, thank you very much for the insights.

Comment: If you don't mind, you can update the answer to give the final solution. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey again, I can add the two lines above the initial line in the migration, but that is not necessarily the best solution. Can you post the contents of your `is_system_message?` method (and any methods it may happen to call)? Thanks, and hope we can get squared away.

Comment: Hi William, the `is_system_message` is only a boolean field in the table. When the system creates a comment, it sets this value for true. I´ve also tought this was not the best way to solve the problem... but couldn´t find anything better.

Comment: Hey, that makes sense for `is_system_message?`. I also re-checked that link you posted above, and when I had viewed it before, the page did not scroll to the related section so I was not sure what the link was for. This time, it did; and I noted the fix there and updated my answer accordingly. You may also be able to revert to the `Comment.all.each do |comment| unless comment.is_system_message? if comment.user comment.update_attribute(:commenter_name, comment.user.name ) else comment.update_attribute(:commenter_name, "User deleted" ) end end end` you used before. Good luck!